# Use sed to replace `,` within brackets

Tags: sed

I'd like to replace commas within brackets with spaces (and also remove the brackets). I used `sed`, but the solution I could come up to is dependent on the elements in the list.

```
sed 's/\[\(.*\), \(.*\)\]/\1 \2/g'

# [-0.0, 1.23]       => -0.0 1.23   (works)
# [-0.0, 1.23, 4.56] => -0.0, 1.23 4.56 (doesn't work)
# foo=[12.3, 4.5, 3.0, 4.1], bar=123.0, xyz=6.7 => foo=12.3, 4.5, 3.0 4.1, bar=123.0, xyz=6.7` (doesn't work, expected: foo=12.3 4.5 3.0 4.1, bar=123.0, xyz=6.7)
```

Is there any way `sed` can be used to do what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this test file:

```
$ cat file
[-0.0, 1.23]
[-0.0, 1.23, 4.56]
foo=[12.3, 4.5, 3.0, 4.1], bar=123.0, xyz=6.7
[1,2,-3,4]
```

To remove any commas within square brackets and also the remove square brackets:

```
$ sed -E ':a; s/(\[[^],]*), */\1 /; ta; s/\[([^]]*)\]/\1/g' file
-0.0 1.23
-0.0 1.23 4.56
foo=12.3 4.5 3.0 4.1, bar=123.0, xyz=6.7
1 2 -3 4
```

#### How it works

- `:a`

  This defines a label `a`.
- `s/(\[[^],]*), */\1 /`

  This looks for the first comma within a square bracket and removes it.

  `[^],]` matches any character except `]` or `,`.  Thus, `(\[[^],]*)` matches `[` followed by any  number of characters not `]` or `,` and stores the result in group 1.
- `ta`

  If the above substitution resulted in a change, jump back to label `a` so we can try the substitution again.
- `s/\[([^]]*)\]/\1/g`

  After we have finished removing commas, this removes the square brackets.

  Note that `[^]]` matches any character that is **not** `]`.  Thus `\[([^]]*)\]` matches a `[` followed by any number of any character except `]` followed by `]`.  In other words, it matches a  single bracketed expression and the contents of the expression, excluding the square brackets, are stored in group 1.

Comment: Seems to fail on the case `echo "[1,2,3,4]" | sed -E ':a; s/(\[[^],]*), /\1 /; ta; s/\[([^]]*)\]/\1/g'`. This returns `1,2,3,4` (including the comma)

Comment: @kvantour That's true.  All of the OP's examples & his code, however, were for comma-blank.  So, that's what my code requires too. Your example, of course, has no blank after the comma.  If you want to make the spaces optional, use: `sed -E ':a; s/(\[[^],]*), */\1 /; ta; s/\[([^]]*)\]/\1/g'`

Comment: True ... but in that formatting, the space can be replaced with a minus sign. This space is generally the location of the sign.

Comment: @kvantour  OK. If you want to make the blank optional, add a star: `sed -E ':a; s/(\[[^],]*), */\1 /; ta; s/\[([^]]*)\]/\1/g'`

Comment: I know, I was just indicating that it might be a minor correction. You could even replace it with `[- ]`.

Comment: @kvantour OK.  I just updated the answer to make the blank-after-comma optional.  Thanks.